# Natural topology on a particular subset of the set of continuous maps from $[0,1]^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, function-spaces

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^\ast$ and
$$F = \{f \in \mathcal{C}([0,1]^n,\mathbb{R}) : f \text{ is convex and } f|_{\mathrm{int}(I)} \text{ is } C^1\}$$
where $\mathcal{C}([0,1]^n,\mathbb{R})$ is the set of continuous maps from $[0,1]^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

**Is there a natural topology on this set ?** I thought about the topology induced by the compact-open topology on $\mathcal{C}([0,1]^n,\mathbb{R})$ but I heard in some paper about the "$C^1$-compact-open topology" in the following framework: if we consider the set
$$F' = \{f \in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}) : f \text{ is convex and } C^1\}$$
then the author describes it as the topology such that its subbase consists of all sets of the form $\{f \in F' : \forall x \in K, f(x) \in O \text{ and } \nabla_x f \in O'\}$, where $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact, $O \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open and $O' \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open.

- Is this a "classical" topology" ? Do you have some references ? What is its interest, compared to the compact-open topology ?
- As $[0,1]^n$ is not a smooth manifold, I don't really know if it is relevant in my case...
- Is $F'$, endowed with this topology, metrizable ?

If you have some advices (**or even other propositions**), thanks in advance !

Comment: This is the [Whitney $C^1$-topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_topologies). This [description](https://planetmath.org/mathcalcrtopologies) might be easier to recognise. $[0,1]$ is a smooth *manifold with boundary*. The distinction is mostly, but not always, irrelevant. The topology is metrisable (see the links).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Tyrone. 1- Is this a ""mistake"" to consider the compact-open topology on $F$ instead of this topology ? 2- In which sense is this irrelevant ? Don't you need to have manifolds to talk about differentiability (I never studied manifolds with boundary, so it might be a naive question) ?

Comment: $1)$ I don't know why it would be a 'mistake' to consider the compact-open topology. However if you are interested in $C^1$ maps, then it would be remiss not to consider the $C^1$-topology also. $2)$ I can't see any problems with working with $[0,1]^n$.

Comment: 1- That's what I meant by "mistake": it would be remiss.

Comment: 2- Because I don't know if it is allowed to talk about $C^1$ maps on manifolds with boundary. Moreover I will need to use characterization of minima of maps of $F$ in terms of differential/gradient and I don't know if there are the same properties with manifolds with boundary.